# Numpy behavior with ** and integer overflows

Tags: python, numpy

I was using this line:

```
(r[i][j]-g[i][j])**2+((r[i][j]-b[i][j])*(g[i][j]-b[i][j]))
```

Where the `[i][j]` addresses are for a 2-d array, and the values within arrays `r`, `g`, and `b` are unsigned 8 bit integers (`np.uint8`).
When `r[i][j]= 162`, `b[i][j]= 133` and `g[i][j] = 142`, the following happens for:

```
(r[i][j]-b[i][j])*(g[i][j]-b[i][j]) = 05
```

I realize that this is an integer overflow by looking at some SO answers searching for unexpected behaviour with multiplication and exponentiation (intermediate result is 261, but the max value is 255, so the counter rolls).

However,

```
(r[i][j]-g[i][j])**2 = 400
```

Why does this *not* overflow?

Comment: I suspect it's because `2` is not `np.uint8`, so the result is a normal `int` rather than `np.uint8`.

Comment: You are right. `(np.uint8(162) - np.uint8(142)) ** np.uint8(2)`

Comment: https://www.dailysmarty.com/posts/numpy-upcasting